# Copy a Ubuntu install?

Tags: 11.04, windows, dual-boot, re-installation

So short story is that I am wanting to grab my ubuntu install, back up to an external disk, delete everything from my hdd, repartition my hdd, put my ubuntu install back.

Long story is.

I finally got my recovery discs, so I do not need to recovery partitions, not the mention my hdd is kinda messy, So I am going to wipe it and put everything back.

Thing is I don't want to have to re-install everything, I would rather just copy/paste my ubuntu install if possible.

Oh, What I should also mention is that I will be dual booting windows!

Comment: What are you backing up to?

Comment: portable hardrive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like

```
sudo rsync -avx --exclude=".gvfs" / /path/to/backup/folder/
```

(The -x option makes it ignore other filesystems, which makes it work even on a running system, which is great for backups!) You will want to do this step for each partition you decide to back up.

Once you have the partitions the way you want and windows installed, I would boot a Ubuntu LiveCD/USB. Then mount the new partition and backup partition and run something like

```
sudo rsync -avx --exclude=".gvfs" /path/to/backup/folder/ /path/to/new/mounted/partition/
```

You will want to do this step for each partition you want to restore.

Run `sudo blkid` to get the uuid of each of the new partitions. Then run

```
gksudo gedit /path/to/new/mounted/partition/etc/fstab
```

and change the UUIDs and then save the file.

Then I would follow the instructions on [Grub2 Reinstalling from LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD) in the "Method 3-Chroot" section to install Grub and let it detect the new disk layout.

Comment: `--exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev` would be a good idea if you want to take this approach.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: the `-x` option do not consider mounted filesystems, so `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` should already be excluded.

Comment: it could be necessary to modify `/etc/fstab`, it is worth notice this. Also, in the restore of the backed-up partition probably the `--exclude` is not necessary.

Comment: @enzotib Thanks for reminding me of that part. @Lekensteyn I've used this method a couple of times to back up and restore systems, and -x option does the trick (but thanks for pointing the exclude thing out just in case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Clonezilla, or, if you prefer a nice GUI solution, Paragon Backup & Recovery 2011 (Advanced) Free (require a Windows PC).

http://clonezilla.org/

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can copy /home to a new partition, then copy it back to your new installation.  Guide here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-partplan/index.html

You can also create a custom iso, though I've never done that.  Some starter info here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

And tons more if you google 'create custom ubuntu iso'.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really sure, but you can try 
[Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html)

for installation
[Install](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10920227)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do a fresh install and re-install the packages that you have installed.

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=261366) is a guide on exporting / importing a list of installed applications.
As has been mentioned in other replies you can back up your /home first and copy it back.